# chrome(osx) bug: select tag css border 0

Tags: css, google-chrome

## chrome(osx) bug: select tag css border 0

i want a border 0 select tag, so I set border style of select tag to 0,then I get what i want.
But its default inset shadow overflows the border.
(the picture below shows the bug in chrome.)
**i want to keep everything of the select tag(border=0) except the overflowing shadow.**
Anybody can help me.

```css
select{border:0;}
```

[image: select tag bug]

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
select{
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   box-shadow: none !important;
}
:-webkit-autofill { 
  color: #fff !important; 
}

select:focus {
  outline: none; 
}
```

Comment: thank u for your answer ,but the css above will remove the default drop down button. This is not i want.